# Comparing two lines in BASH using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have text file like this.

```
2015-11-24 12:59:37.112 128.206.6.136 source
2014-11-24 12:59:36.920 8.8.8.8 source
2014-11-24 14:59:38.112 23.234.22.106 destination
2014-11-24 13:59:37.113 23.234.22.106 source
2014-11-24 12:59:29.047 74.125.198.141 source
2014-12-25 12:59:36.920 74.125.198.148 destination
```

If a particular Ip address is tagged as source as well destination, then I want to tag that Ip as **both**. In this case, Ip 23.234.22.106 is source as well as destination. So, I want to tag it as **both**.

My desired output should be like this

```
2015-11-24 12:59:37.112 128.206.6.136 source
2014-11-24 12:59:36.920 8.8.8.8 source
2014-11-24 14:59:38.112 23.234.22.106 both
2014-11-24 12:59:29.047 74.125.198.141 source
2014-12-25 12:59:36.920 74.125.198.148 destination
```

This is what I have tried.

```
cat input.txt | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq | while read line

do 
grep $line input.txt | sort -r -k1 | head -1
done
```

But, I don't understand how to tag a particular Ip as **both** if it is source as well as destination. In this case, 23.234.22.106.

How can I do it using awk? 
Any help with this would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: In your text file, will all destination and source entries with the same IP be next to each other?

Comment: Yes. They are going to be next to each other

Comment: Ok, that makes things easier. The program only needs to remember the previous lines IP. I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `sed`

```
sed '
    N    #add next line
    s/\([0-9.]\+\)\s\S\+\n.*\s\1\s\S\+$/\1 both/
    P    #print first line from two
    D    #remove first line, return to start
    ' input.txt
```

- `[0-9.]\+` group of numbers and dots
- `\s` space or tab
- `\S\+` group of non-space symbols
- `\n` new line
- `.*` any symbols
- `\1` back reference for group in parethesis `\(...\)`
- `$` pattern end

(modified: remove `t` command (tnx 2[jthill](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/18837/jthill)) and add \space before group to check full address)

Comment: It works. That is some hardcore use of regex. Can you explain the code please? Thank you

Comment: I have a bit similar problem like this but there is major change in input text. Can you please help me with that. Here is the link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288227/comparing-3-lines-and-2-lines-in-bash    Thank you!

Comment: You don't even need the `t`, the `P; D` pair has the same effect on a one-single-line buffer.

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my @lines=();

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  s/#.*//g;        # strip comments
  s/^\s*|\s*$//g;  # strip leading and trailing spaces
  next if (/^$/);  # skip blank lines

  if (! scalar @lines) {
    # store the first line of the file in the array
    # we can't do anything else yet, so skip to the next line.
    push @lines, $_;
    next;
  } else {
    push @lines, $_;

    # split both lines into space-separated fields.
    my @a = split /\s+/, $lines[0];
    my @b = split /\s+/, $lines[1];

    # if 3rd fields are the same, change to "both"
    if ($a[2] eq $b[2]) {
      @lines = map { $_ =~ s/(source|destination)$/both/oi; $_} @lines;
    }
  }
  print $lines[0],"\n";
  shift @lines;
}
print $lines[0],"\n";
```

The idea here is to use an array (`@lines`) to hold the current line and the previous line.  If the 3rd field (perl-arrays are zero-based) of both lines are the same then change the strings "source" or "destination" to "both".

Print the previous line, whether they were changed or not.  Then delete the previous line from the array, using `shift` so that on the next pass through the loop, the current line will be the previous line.

Finally, after the loop has finished, print the last input line.

Output:

```
$ ./swatesh.pl <swatesh.txt 
2015-11-24 12:59:37.112 128.206.6.136 source
2014-11-24 12:59:36.920 8.8.8.8 source
2014-11-24 14:59:38.112 23.234.22.106 both
2014-11-24 13:59:37.113 23.234.22.106 both
2014-11-24 12:59:29.047 74.125.198.141 source
2014-12-25 12:59:36.920 74.125.198.148 destination
```

Some Notes:

The `sed` script works well, so why might you choose to use `perl` instead?  What are the differences?

@Costas' `sed` version is faster, which might be significant if you have millions of lines to process.

This `perl` version explicitly checks if field 3 on both lines is exactly the same, while the `sed` version only checks to see if a pattern that looks similar to an IP address is repeated later in the same joined double-line (which is not necessarily a problem - for your sample input, the `sed` version works perfectly.  It's optimised for exactly your sample).

The `perl` version is probably easier to adapt to different input.

The code at the start of the loop is a useful bit of code I use in many perl scripts to skip blank lines and to support `#` comments in text files.  I often do the same in `sed` scripts but the longer a sed script becomes, the less readable it is...and I like to write code that I can understand at a glance in 6 months time.

Aside from these relatively minor details, both scripts use a very similar algorithm.