# Comparing 3 lines and 2 lines in BASH

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
2014-11-24 12:59:42.169 101.0.0.0 source
2014-11-24 12:59:40.375 104.156.80.0 destination
2014-11-24 12:59:36.729 104.219.48.0 destination
2014-11-24 12:59:40.377 104.37.160.0 source
2014-11-24 12:58:58.902 107.188.128.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:06.456 107.188.128.0 source
2014-11-24 12:59:06.840 107.192.0.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:42.043 107.192.0.0 destination
2014-11-24 12:58:58.904 107.192.0.0 source
2014-11-24 12:59:55.488 111.0.0.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:30.007 111.0.0.0 destination
2014-11-24 12:59:33.209 108.175.32.0 destination
2014-11-24 12:59:06.841 108.175.32.0 source
```

- For IP 107.188.128.0 which is tagged as **both and source**, I just want to tag it as **both**.
- For IP 107.192.0.0 which is tagged as **both, destination and source**, I just want to tag it as **both**.
- For IP 111.0.0.0 which is tagged as **both and destination**, I just want to tag it as **both**.
- For IP 107.192.0.0 which is tagged as **destination and source**, I just want to tag it as **both**.

My desired output should be like this:

```
2014-11-24 12:59:42.169 101.0.0.0 source
2014-11-24 12:59:40.375 104.156.80.0 destination
2014-11-24 12:59:36.729 104.219.48.0 destination
2014-11-24 12:59:40.377 104.37.160.0 source
2014-11-24 12:59:06.456 107.188.128.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:42.043 107.192.0.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:55.488 111.0.0.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:33.209 108.175.32.0 both
```

in which the latest date and time matching the IP are output.

This is what I have tried:

```
awk '{print $3}' input.txt | sort -u | while read line

do 
grep $line input.txt | head -1 
done
```

But, it doesn't work with IP 108.175.32.0.

And this solution:

```
  sed '
      N
      s/\([0-9.]\)\s\S\+\n.*\1\s\S\+$/\1 both/
      t
      P
      D
      ' input.txt
```

But that works *only* with 108.175.32.0.

Is it possible to get the desired output in one shot using `awk` or `sed`? 
I am terribly stuck at this point.

Comment: Please specify which date field should be output.

Comment: @agc the latest date and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is similar like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286978/89144) with a little modification:

```
| sed '
    :1
    N    #add next line
    s/\([0-9.]\+\)\s\S\+\n.*\s\1\s\S\+$/\1 both/
    t1   #go to point 1 if exchange took place
    P    #print first line from two
    D    #remove first line, return to start
    '
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{ip="nothing" 
    time=""
    type=""
 }
 {
    # if the currently processed ip is not the same as the line 
    # being processed then we need to print the data.
    if (ip != $3)
    {
       # if ip == nothing then this is the first line do not print.
       # otherwise we are at a line with a new ip and we should print
       # the data saved from previous lines.
       if(ip != "nothing")
       { 
          print time, ip, type
       }
    # Remove the time update line since we are now doing it outside the
    # if statement so it always updates the time. This will make the 
    # outputted line print the last time stamp for each IP.
    #time=$1" "$2
    ip=$3
    type=$4
    }
    else if (type != $4)
    {
       type="both"
    }
    # no matter what update the time stamp value so that the latest
    # time stamp is kept for any given ip. Putting it after the if
    # that handles when a new ip is found, makes sure that it does not
    # override the value printed for the old ip line.
    time=$1" "$2
 }
 END{
    # Once we reach the end of the input, we still have 
    # the last set of values to print.
    print time, ip, type
 }'
```

It will read the file and if there are two consecutive lines with the same ip and different type (des, src, both) it will change the type to both otherwise if a new ip is found in the data, it will print the type it had..

Comment: It works perfectly fine.But, how can I make it select the latest time and date ?

Comment: Make it update that time variable at every line. I will update the solution for you.

Comment: It doesn't select latest date and time. For ip 107.192.0.0, time stamp should be `2014-11-24 12:59:42.043`. But, it selects, `2014-11-24 12:58:58.904` How can we do this?

Comment: The original implementation would have picked the first time stamp that appears in the input, the second will pick the time stamp from the last line with that ip. It looks like the input has the time stamps for each ip with the most recent at the top so you want the original implementation unless that order is not guaranteed. Are you saying that the order of the input lines is arbitrary?

Comment: In the first case, it was picking latest time stamp but not for all IPs. Yes, it is arbitrary. Although, I am sorting first 3 fields as `cat some_input | sort -r -k1 -k2 -k3 | sort -uk3 > input.txt` . input.txt is a file which is being used in this post.

Comment: If my input.txt file has time difference greater or equal to 24 hours then picking up latest time stamp does matter. Otherwise, the difference of few seconds or minutes is fine and the first code you uploaded would be good to use. Thanks.

Comment: I figured it was something like that.. Ok considering the date time format, you can use sort to achieve this for you :) use the latest code I have up there, then do cat some_input | sort -k3 -k1 -k2 | awk <command above> it will sort by the ip entries first then date then time and the simple nature of the way the date and time are it will actually work for you.. if you want you can -u to remove duplicate lines but the script should ignore that.

Comment: It did not help. I think `cat some_input | sort -r -k1 -k2 -k3 | sort -uk3 > input.txt` and your first version of code was better . Thank you @Rob.

Answer (score 1):

Given input file *foo.txt*:

1. `sort` the first three fields numerically,
2. use [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/) to do the real work of combining IP tags,
3. `cut` a redundant field,
4. then use `sed` to replace any combined tags with "both".

   ```
   sort -r -k1n -k2n -k3n foo.txt | \
     datamash -W -f -s -g3 collapse 4 | \
     cut --complement -f4 | \
     sed 's/\t[sdb].*,.*$/\tboth/g'
   ```

Output:

```
2014-11-24  12:59:42.169    101.0.0.0       source
2014-11-24  12:59:40.375    104.156.80.0    destination
2014-11-24  12:59:36.729    104.219.48.0    destination
2014-11-24  12:59:40.377    104.37.160.0    source
2014-11-24  12:59:06.456    107.188.128.0   both
2014-11-24  12:59:42.043    107.192.0.0     both
2014-11-24  12:59:33.209    108.175.32.0    both
2014-11-24  12:59:55.488    111.0.0.0       both
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the typo `destinatiion` in the input file (or modify the script to use `destinati?ion` so that it copes with the mis-spelling) then the output of my [perl script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287111/7696) answer for your last question can be piped into `uniq -f2` to get your desired output.

The `-f2` option tells `uniq` to skip the first two fields when comparing lines for uniqueness.

e.g. with the `@lines = map ...` line in the perl script changed to:

```
@lines = map { $_ =~ s/(source|destinati?ion)$/both/oi; $_} @lines;
```

The output looks like this:

```
$ ./swatesh.pl < swatesh2.txt | uniq -f2
2014-11-24 12:59:42.169 101.0.0.0 source
2014-11-24 12:59:40.375 104.156.80.0 destinatiion
2014-11-24 12:59:36.729 104.219.48.0 destinatiion
2014-11-24 12:59:40.377 104.37.160.0 source
2014-11-24 12:58:58.902 107.188.128.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:06.840 107.192.0.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:55.488 111.0.0.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:33.209 108.175.32.0 both
```

If you want the *latest* date and time output, then first sort the input in reverse order by IP address (field 3) and then date and time (fields 1 & 2) before piping it into my perl script (swatesh.pl) and `uniq -f2`.  Optionally sort the final output so that it is in ascending date+time order.  e.g.

```
$ sort -r -k3,3 -k1,2 swatesh2.txt | ./swatesh.pl | uniq -f2 | sort     
2014-11-24 12:59:06.456 107.188.128.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:33.209 108.175.32.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:36.729 104.219.48.0 destinatiion
2014-11-24 12:59:40.375 104.156.80.0 destinatiion
2014-11-24 12:59:40.377 104.37.160.0 source
2014-11-24 12:59:42.043 107.192.0.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:42.169 101.0.0.0 source
2014-11-24 12:59:55.488 111.0.0.0 both
```

Comment: when I run your code, my output is same as input text. Why is that ?

Comment: are you running it with the input exactly as in your question, or are you changing it in some way (e.g. with sort) first?

Comment: Exactly in the same way given in the question. Thanks @cas

Comment: and are you piping it through `uniq -f2` after my script?   if not, i think you'll find the output isn't the **same** as the input, it will have some lines with 'source' or 'destination' changed to 'both'.  btw, i changed the answer a bit...your input data wasn't ordered as i thought it was so i used `sort` instead of `tac`

Comment: Yes. I am piping it through uniq -f2

Comment: I just noticed that the version of the perl script in the other answer is slightly older than the version I am running here.  I made one crucial change to it here, but forgot to update the script in the answer when i updated the sample output.  The line that has `print join("\n",@lines),"\n";` has to be changed to `print $lines[0],"\n";`.  I've updated the script now in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made the script below.  It sorts the result by date.
Call it *fix.sh*, invoke `bash fix.sh <LOGFILENAME>`

```
function fix {
    while read IP TYPE HOUR DATE; do
        if [ ! -z "$PREVIOUS_IP" ]; then
            if [ $IP == $PREVIOUS_IP ]; then
                TYPE=both
                [[ $DATE < $PREVIOUS_DATE ]] && DATE="$PREVIOUS_DATE"
                EQUAL_IPS=true
            else
                echo $PREVIOUS_LINE
                EQUAL_IPS=false
            fi
        fi
        PREVIOUS_DATE="$DATE"
        PREVIOUS_IP=$IP;
        PREVIOUS_LINE="$IP $TYPE $HOUR $DATE";
    done
    [ "$EQUAL_IPS" == true ] && echo $PREVIOUS_LINE
}

LOGFILE=$1

cat $LOGFILE | awk '{print $3 " " $4 " " $1 " " $2;}' | \
  sort | fix | awk '{print $3 " " $4 " " $1 " " $2;}' | sort
```

Its output is:

```
2014-11-24 12:59:06.456 107.188.128.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:33.209 108.175.32.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:36.729 104.219.48.0 destination
2014-11-24 12:59:40.375 104.156.80.0 destination
2014-11-24 12:59:40.377 104.37.160.0 source
2014-11-24 12:59:42.043 107.192.0.0 both
2014-11-24 12:59:42.169 101.0.0.0 source
2014-11-24 12:59:55.488 111.0.0.0 both
```

Comment: The tags are correct. But, the time stamp are not as required. I want to print latest time stamp. By latest I mean new or fresh. For ip 107.192.0.0, time stamp should be `2014-11-24 12:59:42.043`. But, it selects, `2014-11-24 12:58:58.904`. How can I do this?

Comment: @Swatesh, now it should be working as you want. The script now will preserve the latest date for lines with the same ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code given in OP:

```
awk '{print $3}' input.txt | sort -u | while read line
do 
    echo -n `grep $line input.txt | \
      sort -r | head -1 | \
      grep -oe "[^a-z]*"` ' ' # print latest time stamp
    if [[ $(grep -c $line input.txt) -ge 2 ]];  then 
        echo  'both'
    else
        echo `grep $line input.txt | grep -oe "[a-z]*"`
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
2014-11-24 12:59:42.169 101.0.0.0  source
2014-11-24 12:59:40.375 104.156.80.0  destination
2014-11-24 12:59:36.729 104.219.48.0  destination
2014-11-24 12:59:40.377 104.37.160.0  source
2014-11-24 12:59:06.456 107.188.128.0  both
2014-11-24 12:59:42.043 107.192.0.0  both
2014-11-24 12:59:33.209 108.175.32.0  both
2014-11-24 12:59:55.488 111.0.0.0  both
```